# How to search for values and nested array values

Tags: typescript, search, ionic4

There is a product objects array with different values.

```js
products: object[] = [];
```

The product array is filled with products. Some with **tags**, some without.

```
[
  { _id: 'xxx',
    name: 'ProductA',
    price: '1',
    tags: [ 'tag1', 'tag2' ]
  },
  { _id: 'yyy',
    name: 'ProductB',
    price: '5'
  }
]
```

The products have to be searchable through **`NAME`, `PRICE` and `TAGS`**

We use the ion-searchbar in Ionic 4 with the following code in the ts file

```js
searchProducts(param: any): void {
  const val: string = param;
  this.resetProducts();

  if (val.trim() !== '') {
      this.products = this.products.filter(product => {
        return (
          product.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
          product.price.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
          product.tags.filter((tag: string) => {
            return tag.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1
          });
        );
      });
  } else if (val.trim() === '') {
    this.resetProducts();
  }
}
```

The result for every search is all the products in the products Array. 
If we remove the tag filter and search for name and price only, the function provides us with the correct results.

Can someone point to the right direction to get the function to return values for name, price and tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple fix, just add `products.tags &&`.

Also, change `product.tags.filter` to `product.tags.some`.

This is because if there's no matches for any tag, `filter` will return `[]`, which will be coerce to `true` in logical experssion`.

```
searchProducts(param: any): void {
  const val: string = param;
  this.resetProducts();

  if (val.trim() !== '') {
      this.products = this.products.filter(product => {
        return (
          product.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
          product.price.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
          product.tags && product.tags.some((tag: string) => {
            return tag.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1
          });
        );
      });
  } else if (val.trim() === '') {
    this.resetProducts();
  }
}
```

To code above can actually be converted into the code below to reduce noises.

```
searchProducts(param: any): void {
  const val: string = param;
  this.resetProducts();

  if (val.trim() !== '') {
      this.products = this.products.filter(product => 
          [
            product.name,
            product.price,
            ...(product.tags || [])
          ].some(value => value.toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase()))
      );
  } else if (val.trim() === '') {
    this.resetProducts();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Implemented your solution, but I still get all the products in the products Array when entering a search.

Comment: Apology, you need to change `product.tags.filter` to `product.tags.some`. Please look at my latest answer.

Comment: Yes, works perfectly now. I see, if a tag passes the indexOf > -1, it returns. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

Edit

```
product.tags.filter((tag: string) => {
            return tag.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1
});
```

To

```
product.tags.some((tag: string) => {
                if(!tag) return false;
                return tag.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1
});
```

EDIT:
Use some() method instead of filter()
filter() returns a new array with all of the elements of this array for which the provided filtering function returns true.
where as some() returns if at least one element in this array satisfies the provided testing function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Implemented your solution, but I still get all the products in the products Array when entering a search.

Comment: Oops! There has been an oversight. As Wong mentioned use some() method instead of filter().

Answer (score 0):

```
[
  { _id: 'xxx',
    name: 'ProductA',
    price: '1',
    tags: [ 'tag1', 'tag2' ]
  },
  { _id: 'yyy',
    name: 'ProductB',
    price: '5'
  }
] 


Based on your method on searchProducts, you are filtering the tags key in the products array but product array doesn't have the `TAGS` key as per your sample above.

product.tags.filter((tag: string) => {
                return tag?tag.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1:false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Implemented your solution, but I still get all the products in the products Array when entering a search.

Answer (score 0):

Here a slightly cleaner version of solution posted by @WongJiaHau:

```
const searchProducts = (param: string): void => {
  param = param.toLowerCase();
  this.resetProducts();

  if (param.trim() === '') {
    return;
  }

  const some = (list: string[]) => list.some(v => v.toLowerCase().includes(param));
  this.products = this.products
    .map(p => ({...p, tags: p.tags || []}))
    .filter(some);
}
```